# Highcharts - Assign a color to a specific value when data is dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, highcharts, sharepoint-2013

**NOTE: INTRANET BASED PROJECT

The project I'm working on utilizes HighCharts to generate a pie chart.  The data for this pie chart is dynamically created by querying a SharePoint List using REST API.  We have 9 charts total being created this way, and 8 of them have a filter applied to narrow results to a specific group instead of Overall.  The problem is the colors for the slices are not consistent because the values are not in the same order each time the data is queried and assembled into our dataArray.  What we would like to try and do is assign a color to each datapoint value, so that the colors stay consistent.

For example:

```
Resource = #123ABC
Lost Resource = #456DEF
User Error = #789GHI
```

We would then need to loop through our DataArray, and apply those values to that pie slice, if it exists in that dataset.  Our dataset is for example:

```
[Resource, 81.6],[Lost Resource, 1.0],[User Error, 0.01]
```

Again, our data is dynamic so our actual series code is:

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: chartTitle,
            data: countArray,
        }]
```

---

Below is the full code we're working with:

Utility.js File (processes data into countArray)

```
"use strict";

var EngagementChartBuilder = window.EngagementChartBuilder || {};

EngagementChartBuilder.Utilities = function () {
var buildCategoryCounts = function (countArray, dataArray) {
    if (countArray == undefined) {
        countArray = [];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        var currValue = parseInt(dataArray[i].hours);
        var currName = dataArray[i].reason;
        var found = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < countArray.length; j++) {
            if (countArray[j][0] == currName) {
                found = true;
                var newCount = countArray[j][1];
                countArray[j][1] = newCount + currValue;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            countArray.push([currName, currValue]);
        }
    }

    return countArray;
},

loadPieChart = function (countArray, colorArray, divId, chartTitle) {
    //Build Pie Chart
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    })
    $(divId).highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        colors: colorArray,

        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.y} hours</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b> {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: chartTitle,
            data: countArray,
        }]
    });
}
```

---

ViewModel.js REST QUERY

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
Array.prototype.filter = function (fun /*, thisp */) {
    "use strict";

    if (this == null)
        throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
        throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in t) {
            var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
            if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
                res.push(val);
        }
    }

    return res;
};
}

"use strict";

var EngagementChartBuilder = window.EngagementChartBuilder || {};

EngagementChartBuilder.EngagementsPieChart_COR = function () {
var load = function () {
    $.when(
        //Empire Engagements List
        EngagementChartBuilder.RESTQuery.execute("QA_TimeMgtPerRelease", "$select=*,ProjectRelease/CALCReportGroup,Reason_x0020_Type,CalculatedSubtotal&$filter=(((Reason_x0020_Type%20ne%20'Weekend%20Hours')%20and%20(Reason_x0020_Type%20ne%20'After%20Hours'))%20and%20(ProjectRelease/CALCReportGroup%20eq%20'COR'))&$top=2000")
    ).done(
        function (engagements1) {
            var dataArray = [];
            var countArray = [];

            //Get data from Empire Engagements List
            var results = engagements1.d.results;
            var filtered = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].ProjectRelease/CALCReportGroup == 'COR') {
                    filtered.push(results[i]);
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                var reason = filtered[i].Reason_x0020_Type;
                var hours = filtered[i].CalculatedSubtotal;
                dataArray[i] = { 'hours': hours, 'reason': reason };
            }

            countArray = EngagementChartBuilder.Utilities.buildCategoryCounts(countArray, dataArray);

            //Build Chart
            EngagementChartBuilder.Utilities.loadPieChart CountArray, "#engagementPieChart_COR", "Testing Time vs. Time Lost (COR)");
        }
    ).fail(
        function (engagements1) {
            $("#engagementPieChart_COR").html("<strong>An error has occurred.</strong>");
        }
    );
};

return {
    load: load
}
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using array as point, use object as point, simple changes:

```
countArray.push([currName, currValue]);
```

to:

```
countArray.push({ name: currName, y: currValue, color: 'red' });
```

And second change:

```
var newCount = countArray[j][1];
countArray[j][1] = newCount + currValue;
```

to:

```
var newCount = countArray[j].y;
countArray[j].y = newCount + currValue;
```

Comment: Ok, I understand your reasoning in that.  My question then is how would I then define a color to a specific Name?  so basically if currName = Resource, then it should always be x color.  If currName = User Error, then it should always be z color.

Comment: Just create a global map:  `var colorMap = {'User Error': 'red', 'Resource': 'green'}`, then use `countArray.push({ name: currName, y: currValue, color: colorMap[currName] });`

Comment: I've attempted to implement this, but it's not forcing consistent colors for each currName.  Nothing has actually changed.

Comment: Strange, it should work as @Mark described. Anyway, where do you have stored colors for each series? Could have such information in `dataArray` ? Like: `dataArray[i] = { color: 'red', 'hours': hours, 'reason': reason };` Then you may set color using `var color = dataArray[i].color;countArray.push({ name: currName, y: currValue, color: color });`.